# Escapar "/" de /d Regex con mas "/"

Tags: java, regex

Necesito validar una expresion que tiene esta pinta :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- El patron tiene que estar al comenzar la cadena siempre.
- El numero interior tiene que ser positivo ( valiendo el 0 ) hasta el infinito (siendo siempre el valor entero ).
- Tiene que estar contenido entre **/** y **/** los digitos.

Tengo problemas de que solo me reconozca numeros entre un slash y otro , he probado bastantes alternativas pero no hay manera os pongo el intento que mas cerca he andado.

El problema creo que es con las slash , que no se ponerlas o no las detecta bien para coger el **/d** tal como indica la [api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

```
       public static void checkString (String s) {
        boolean yes = s.matches("^/[\\d\\/].*");
        System.out.println ("'" + s + "': " + yes);
    }

    public static void main (String s[]) {
        checkString ("Hi/Hello/Bye/");
        checkString ("Hi/90/Hello/Bye\\");
        checkString ("Hi//Hello/Bye\\");
        checkString ("/Hi\\Hello/Bye\\");
        checkString ("//Hi\\Hello/Bye\\");
        checkString ("\\/Hi\\Hello/Bye\\");
        checkString ("/99/Hi\\Hello/Bye\\");//true
        checkString ("a/99/Hi\\Hello/Bye\\");
        checkString ("//Hi\\Hello/Bye\\");
        checkString ("/0/Hi\\Hello/Bye\\");//True
        checkString ("/0a/Hi\\Hello/Bye\\");
        checkString ("/a0/Hi\\Hello/Bye\\");
        checkString ("HiHelloBye");
    }
```

Ideas , sugerencias o aclaraciones son bienvenidas .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo veo en tu expresión regular.

Yo usaría en su lugar:

```
^\/\d+\/.*
```

Que escapado queda como `"^\\/\\d+\\/.*"`

Explicación...

[image: explicaicón gráfica]

A diferencia de la que tenías....

```
^/[\d\/].*
```

Que como podrás ver le falta escapar el caracter `/`. Una vez escapado obtenemos

```
^\/[\d\/].*
```

Que analizado nos da:

[image: análisis de la regex de la pregunta]

Esto debido a que al meter `\d` y `\/` en los corchetes le estás dando a elegir uno de los dos.

Ahora un pequeño comercial de como lo probé con una herramienta hecha por mí mismo llamada [Dukescript Java Regex Tester](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11370-dukescript-java-regex-tester):

Al generar posibles valores a partir de tu expresión regular para tu caso obtengo:

- `/[/]澫訅ꍲ`
- `/[/]辽`
- `/9/]䓁ᎂ`
- `/6/]닌㽍삿`
- `/2/]`

Que como verás permite observar rápidamente el defecto en la expresión regular.

Si usamos la mía obtenermos valores como:

- `/17/뛦`
- `/4/癬`
- `/4/`
- `/05/넑`
- `/880914/遹膨놘`

Que es prácticamente lo que quieres, ya que no especiifcaste si puede o no tener ceros que le precedan.

Answer (score 0):

Para escapar “/” se debe de usar \/ de tal manera que tu  expresión debería quedar algo así:

```
   public static void checkString (String s) {
        boolean yes = s.matches("\\/[0-9]+\\/[0-9a-zA-Z]*");
        System.out.println ("'" + s + "': " + yes);
    }
```

Yo hice estas 3 pruebas y el resultado es:

```
    checkString ("/9/"); //true
    checkString ("//");  //false
    checkString ("/99/cadena");  //true
```

Para el "resto de la cadena" te toca completar la expresión.
Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: el caso de prueba /0/Hi\Hello/Bye\ falla y debería pasar según el usuario

Comment: prueba con \/[0-9]+\/.*

Comment: sip, essa es una buena alternativa a mi respuesta, deberías de editar lo que pusiste, pero no olvides agregarle el anchor ^ para que valide que sea al inicio de línea